# How jenkins manage jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to know how Jenkins manage the queued jobs, I mean does it uses a Message Queue system like rabbitmq or the jobs are treated like threads inside the application?

I just googled for it, but didn't find anything clear.

Regards

Comment: [It's open source, go dive!](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins)

Comment: I can tell you, there is no external message queue system involved.